# Padding between each pie

Tags: javascript, svg

Hi there is there any way to put a white gap between each pie?

I seen this example 
   https ://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/rnLnqq3g/) but

do not know how to modify to have the gaps/padding. Something like the attached image.[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for the broken URL. Tried posing the question using mobile and seems be harder.

Comment: Add some translate transforms to the slices.